# newbie with mahapps, Datagrids look with no style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, mahapps.metro

I'm just started working with the MahApps.Metro theme, and I've noticed that datagrids look as usual, I've tried to add this line to the xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.DataGrid.xaml" />
```

but I get this message: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.DataGrid.xaml

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try just using:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"/>
```

Comment: that line already exists, only datagrids appear with no style

Comment: Would you be able to post your full xaml code? I wonder if you are missing the theme from your resources.

Comment: Having tried both the code in the answer and question nothing works. Any update for the answer?